# How to scroll screen down with dropdown menu with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, mobile, nav

My site is http://868rcacs.ca/index.php and I got the drop down menu to work [Only visable on mobile] and when you press the menu button it drops down properly but I want to get the screen to scroll down as kinda like clicking a like the `href="#namehere"` would scroll to `name="namehere"`

Is it possible to achieve when I'm trying to and if so how would you do it?

Comment: Why do I need a `max-width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to let the window scroll down to see the entire menu? For starters you could make the logo a size smaller, but it is easily done with js, something in a way of:

```
window.scrollTo($anchor.left,$anchor.top)
```

Or jquery:

```
$('body').animate({$anchor: $anchor.top })
```

Edit:
It is also explained here with some more code. http://css-plus.com/2010/11/create-a-scrolling-anchor-link-with-jquery/